# Image at right in jQuery Mobile li element

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

By default, if you put an image in an li element in jquery Mobile, the image is aligned to the left. I want it to be aligned to the right, like this

```
Here is some text  | Image
```

The class `ui-li-thumb` aligns the image to the left. I can't override this class with one of my own. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you can either specify a selector that is more specific than the jQuery Mobile selectors or you can use `!important` to force your CSS rule(s) to be used:

```
.ui-page .ui-content .ui-listview .ui-li-thumb {
    left  : auto;
    right : 1px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BHBJ8/1/

**OR**

```
.ui-li-thumb {
    left  : auto !important;
    right : 1px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BHBJ8/

Notice that since the `.ui-li-thumb` class absolutely positions the element anchored by the left side, we can set `left` to `auto` and give the element a `right` property to align it to the right side of it's offset parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div align="left" class="ui-block-a">
        <h5>18-inch,Split 5-spoke Bright Aluminium-alloy Wheels</h5>
        <img src="images/182x116-13TDI_GSSpecs035.jpg">
    </div>
    <div align="left" class="ui-block-b">
        <h5 >* A distinguished and elegant set of 18-inch,split5-spoke</h5>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This is how the webpage looks

18-inch,split 5-spoke Bright Aluminium Alloy Wheels

Img          | Text